# For a TURN server that supports STUN, do I need to list both STUN and TURN urls in the client?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

If I have a TURN server that can also act as a STUN, should my urls in my client looks like this?

```
myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "turn:example.org"
    }
  ]
});
```

or like this?

```
myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:example.org"
    },
    {
      urls: "turn:example.org"
    }
  ]
});
```

I only want the TURN functionality used if necessary, not for every connection.

Thanks!

Comment: that is the default behaviour of ICE and TURN, it is used as a last resort.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Thanks for the reply. So by your suggestion I want the second sample? And WebRTC will handle the right priority?

Comment: yes. You can actually this this yourself on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
-- with valid credentials a srflx candidate will be gathered when there is just a turn server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like the second option. It will try to connect with the stun server and fallback to the turn server when the stun method doesn't work.